# Laravel vue page is not loading and is pending in the network tab

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got question about Laravel and VueJS. I've built my Vue project with `npm run watch` and I started my Laravel application with `php artisan serve` to serve the app. When I went visit my website-page, the page would not load and is continuing in a infinite loop. In my network tab, I see an API request has been sent to `/js/landing.js`, but he seems to be pending for the whole time.

My application is at the moment running on WSL, but I do not know what problem caused this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you load /js/landing.js in your browser by itself?

Comment: Yes, when I visit the JS page in the browser, it just show the whole file content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe if u re-install npm in VueJS?

another idea maybe is clear the cahe in vue and laravel terminal and test again!

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

and try to check the log file for laravel and vuejs